# Displaying all XMP tags

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, metadata, xmp

I am trying to get all The XMP data from a Image, with the XMP Library from [Adobe](http://cssdk.host.adobe.com/sdk/1.0/docs/WebHelp/references/XMPASLib/XMP_API_Summary.htm).

I will actually like to retrieve the information of the image, so i believe i have to retrieve  data from the name space below.

```
+http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/
+http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/aux/
+http://ns.adobe.com/tiff/1.0/ 
+http://ns.adobe.com/png/1.0/
+http://ns.adobe.com/jpeg/1.0/
```

I tried with the code below:

```
private function init(event:Event):void{
    var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
    ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imgLoaded);

    var s:String = "file:/"+File.desktopDirectory.nativePath + "/IMG_1811.jpg";
    trace("s :"+s +" output \n");

    ldr.load(new URLRequest(s));
}
private function imgLoaded(e:Event):void{
    var info:LoaderInfo = e.target as LoaderInfo;

    var meta2:XMPMeta= new XMPMeta(info.bytes);

    trace("\n\n\n\n\n");
    //trace(meta2.dumpObject());
    trace(meta2.length);

    trace("\n\n\n\n\n");
}
```

But i does not display correctly. It says Error: XML data is not well-formed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [using XMPCore to get metadata of a file through actionscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286566/using-xmpcore-to-get-metadata-of-a-file-through-actionscript)